# Save images from adresses with an ID and a random string part using iMacro

Tags: string, loops, random, imacros

I want to save some images from a website, with addresses like this

```
http://somewebsite.com/{{ID}}_{{rand}}.JPG
```

{{ID}} varies from 01 to 99. The {{rand}} part is a string of 8 random uppercase characters for each ID. For example:

```
http://somewebsite.com/93_ABCDEFGHI.JPG
```

Is it possible to check all cases for the string part? if yes, could you please tell me how?

Comment: Do you realize that there are 208,827,064,576 strings like that?

Comment: @toasted_flakes Why didn't I think of that?!! >_<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still want to get a random string from 208+ milliards:

```
SET frc "function frc() {return String.fromCharCode(65 + Math.floor(Math.random()*26))};"
SET rand EVAL("eval('{{frc}}'); var s = ''; for (i = 1; i <= 8; i++) s += frc(); s;")
http://somewebsite.com/{{ID}}_{{rand}}.JPG
```

(They are practically unrepeatable.)